# Find the way out from the maze in Python

Tags: python, recursion, backtracking, maze

The problem is to find the exit from the maze. I can't find the error in this code.
The maze encoding: 1 - pit (or wall, it depends), 0 - freeway, 2, 3 - visited fields. S - South (down), E - East (left), N - North (up), W - West (left). The `lepes()` is the main function which does the recursive moves. x - horizontal, y - vertical coordinates of the active move. The maze length is 12 x 12 by the way, surrounded by pit (wall, default this means 1). The real playground is a 10 x 10 field. All the visited moves stored in list s, initially `s = []`. The variable `lab` stores the maze.
I just trying to find out the way out of the maze. I have this code in Python:

```
def lepes(x, y, lab, s):
    if x != 10 and y !=10:
        # step forward... 
        lab[x][y] = 3
        # can I move down?
        if x < 11 and lab[x+1][y] == 0 :
            s.append("S")
            lepes(x+1, y, lab, s)
        # can I move right?
        if y < 11 and lab[x][y+1] == 0:
            s.append("E")
            lepes(x, y+1, lab, s)
        # can I move up?
        if x > 0 and lab[x-1][y] == 0:
            s.append("N")
            lepes(x-1, y, lab, s)        
        # can I move left?
        if y > 0 and lab[x][y-1] == 0:
            s.append("W")
            lepes(x, y-1, lab, s)
        #   step back...
        #   mark as visited
        #lab[x][y] = 2
        s.append("")
        #s.pop()
    else:
        # The goal is reached, and last step forward...
        lab[x][y] = 3
        return
        # last step back 
        lab[x][y] = 2
```

To find the way out the maze I tried to call the function `lepes(1, 1, lab, s)` from initial point (1, 1). I have to get to the field with coordinates (10, 10):
With this initial value of `lab`:

```
lab = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]
```

Final form of solution: `"".join(s)`
I've got this:

> s = "SSSSSSSSSEESESSWSEESEEEENNNEEEEWNNNEEEEEEENNEEWWWWWW"

I should have something like this:

> s = "SSSSSEENNNEEEEEEESSWWWWSSSEEEESS"

[image: Maze to solve]

The yellow is the starting point, the greein is the goal.

Comment: maybe a diagram would help

Comment: Ok, @mhlester. Here You are the maze. This could help?

Comment: first of, since you are always starting by testing south, your expected result is wrong, it should be `SSSSSSSSSEENNENNEESEEEESS`

Comment: @beistvan Please see the edit to my answer, showing how to find an even shorter path.

Comment: @Hyperboreus I just looking it now.

Comment: On a side note: Recursion is almost never your weapon of choice in python, as it lacks (by design) TCO.

Answer (score 2):

Your if statements are not exclusive. Inside each one you call the function recursively, but when that recursive call returns, execution just carries on, and can go into one of the other blocks for that same position.

You could probably fix this by changing them to `elif`, but personally I'm not convinced that recursion is the best solution here (unless you're explicitly trying to program in a functional style): better to use a while loop at the top and update `x` and `y` inside each branch of the if.

Comment: This is kind of backtracking algorithm, but in some point after the second corner it turns to the right in the pit instead turning up to free way.

Answer (score 2):

If you are looking for the shortest path, I would suggest the following:

Convert your maze into a weighted graph with the following properties:

- The set of vertices be the set of all passable squares.
- The set of edges be the set of all tuples of adjacent passable squares.
- The weight of each edge be 1.

After this let Mr Dijkstra or A* do the work for you.

---

The shortest path I can find is "SSSSSEESEEESEEEESS".

Here the quick and **dirty** code with which I found it:

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

lab = [[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1],[1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1],[1,0,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1],[1,0,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,0,1,0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1],[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,0,1],[1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]]

class Node:
    def __init__ (self, x, y):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.neighbours = [ (x + xoff, y + yoff) for xoff, yoff in
            ( (1, 0), (0, 1), (0, -1), (-1, 0) )
            if not lab [y + yoff] [x + xoff] ]
        self.distance = ...
        self.path = ...
        self.visited = False

    def __repr__ (self):
        return '{}: ({})'.format ( (self.x, self.y), self.neighbours)

nodes = {}
for y in range (12):
    for x in range (12):
        if lab [y] [x]: continue
        nodes [x, y] = Node (x, y)

current = nodes [1, 1]
current.distance = 0
current.path = []
unvisited = set (nodes.keys () )

while True:
    dist = current.distance + 1
    for nx, ny in current.neighbours:
        if (nx, ny) not in unvisited: continue
        neighbour = nodes [nx, ny]
        if neighbour.distance is ... or neighbour.distance > dist:
            neighbour.distance = dist
            neighbour.path = current.path + [ (current.x, current.y) ]
    current.visited = True
    unvisited.remove ( (current.x, current.y) )
    if not unvisited: break
    current = sorted ( [node for node in nodes.values ()
        if not node.visited and node.distance is not ...],
        key = lambda node: node.distance) [0]

print (nodes [10, 10].path)
path = nodes [10, 10].path + [ (10, 10) ]
for (ax, ay), (bx, by) in zip (path, path [1:] ):
    if ax == bx and ay > by: print ('N', end = '')
    if ax == bx and ay < by: print ('S', end = '')
    if ay == by and ax > bx: print ('W', end = '')
    if ay == by and ax < bx: print ('E', end = '')
print ()
```

Result is:

```
[(1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (1, 4), (1, 5), (1, 6), (2, 6), (3, 6), (3, 7), (4, 7), (5, 7), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8), (8, 8), (9, 8), (10, 8), (10, 9)]
SSSSSEESEEESEEEESS
```

Or if you start for instance at the upper right corner, the result is:

```
[(10, 1), (9, 1), (8, 1), (8, 2), (8, 3), (9, 3), (10, 3), (10, 4), (10, 5), (9, 5), (8, 5), (7, 5), (6, 5), (6, 6), (6, 7), (6, 8), (7, 8), (8, 8), (9, 8), (10, 8), (10, 9)]
WWSSEESSWWWWSSSEEEESS
```